# Creating a vector using a for loop in R and naming it as first column of the row

Tags: r, vector, rename

I am trying to iterate row by row over a dataframe and create a vector. That's not really problematic. What happens is that I need to name each vector according to the character string in the first column of each row.

```
      Eng_Vowel Mean_Eng_F1 Mean_Eng_F2
1     Eng_i   -4.806034    5.260754
2     Eng_I   -3.834577    4.272719
3     Eng_u   -4.882196    2.589861
4     Eng_E   -2.724496    3.091326
5     Eng_A   -1.812763    0.886462
6     Eng_a   -1.324149    3.283093
```

The first step I have is the loop that creates a vector:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
  x <- as.numeric(df[row,2:3])
  }
```

Right now it keeps overwriting x, but the idea is I would like x to be the name of column 1 for each row so that -4.806034    5.260754 would be stored in the vector Eng_i and so on.

If anyone has any thoughts, it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of the vectors you want, then put the list in the global environment:

```
list_of_vectors = split(df[2:3], df$Eng_Vowel)
list2env(list_of_vectors, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```